# How can I put django static files in javascript array?

Tags: javascript, django, django-staticfiles

I need to get static files from django to a "links" array...

```
var links = [
  '/static/uploads/fth/FthAgg.xlsx',
  '/static/uploads/fth/FthCon.xlsx'
];
```

This is the html:

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/pages/fthpage.css' %}">
    <script src="{% static 'js/downloads.js' %}"></script>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1 class="header_h1">FTH Page</h1>
      <button onclick="downloadAll(window.links)">Test me!</button>

    </a>
  </body>
</html>
```

This wont work though. When I try to put https links it will work.
Im doing this so that i can later download these files simultaniously with one button.

Here is my javascript file:
https://pastebin.com/0sCTav8G

Here is my html template:
https://pastebin.com/yvz2AL0M

Comment: Please put the code into the question so that people do not have to visit an external site to view it. You can put \`\`\` above and below the code to make it monospaced.

Comment: the html? or what?

Comment: its a lot of code to put into stackoverflow

Comment: Having looked at your pastebins, it is not a lot of code. both the html and the javascript.

Comment: haha, you clicked it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function downloadAll(links)
{
for (i = 0, len = links.length; i < len; i++) {

 var link = links[i];
 var a = document.createElement("a");
 var file = 'file'+ i + '.xlsx';
 a.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8, ' 
                                         + link); 
                    a.setAttribute('download', file); 
                    a.click();
    
    }    

}
```

Comment: Thanks galex .I left the click event .Thanks again